# Bitbucket - alternative ssh key connection not working

Tags: ssh, bitbucket, ssh-keys

I'm trying to setup alternative ssh key for bitbucket. I've followed this document:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=271943168

My .ssh/config

```
Host test
HostName bitbucket.org
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_alt
```

However the connection using "test" does not work. I debug output looks like this:

When I try to debug:

```
[user@ArchKraken tmp3]$ ssh -Tv git@test
OpenSSH_6.8p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2a 19 Mar 2015
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/user/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for test
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [131.103.20.167] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa_alt type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa_alt-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.8
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr umac-64@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr umac-64@openssh.com none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<3072<8192) sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:zzXQOXSRBEiUtuE8AikJYKwbHaxvSc0ojez9YXaGp1A
debug1: Host 'bitbucket.org' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Remote: Forced command: conq username:otheruser
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Remote: Forced command: conq username:otheruser
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to bitbucket.org ([131.103.20.167]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
logged in as otheruser.

You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 3656, received 3400 bytes, in 0.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 28045.6, received 26081.8
debug1: Exit status 0
```

I'm not sure why, but it appears the connection is eventually established using a wrong id (/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa) regardless of what I specified in IdentityFile in .ssh/config. I suspect it has something to do with:

```
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
```

but I'm not sure why it is unable to find it. I clearly see two files:

```
id_rsa_alt
id_rsa_alt.pub
```

I have a similar setup for github that works.

Comment: Did you end up resolving this? How? I tried the chmod as suggested below, but unfortunately not working still.

Comment: In my comment below I stated that after a restart things started working. It's been a while ago, so I do not remember details. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Strangely after a system restart this started working. I'm still confused why it did not before.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it has something to do with the permission of `id_rsa_alt` key.  Try changing its permission first by executing this command:

`chmod 600 id_rsa_alt`